# HTML/CSS: Common border around overlapping texts

Tags: html, css, styles, position, border

How to code for this?

[image]

When we have this:
[image]

as

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>             
            h2
            {
                letter-spacing:4pt;
                font-size:40pt;
                color:blue;
                text-align:center;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
            }
            h3
            {
                letter-spacing:4pt;
                font-size:40pt;
                color:blue;
                text-align:center;
                position: absolute;
                top:20px;
                left:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>All right, Mate?</h2>
        <h3>All right, Mate?</h3>
    </body>
</html>
</html>
```

...without changing the original functionality/tags.
Only add (or modify) a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both in a wrapper with `position` set to `relative` and define a fixed `width` and `height` to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>All righ, Mate?</h2>
    <h3>All right, Mate?</h3>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper 
{
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 448px;
    height: 89px;
}    
h2
{
    letter-spacing:4pt;
    font-size:40pt;
    color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
h3
{
    letter-spacing:4pt;
    font-size:40pt;
    color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
}​
```

It's necessary to define a `height` because both elements have the `position` set to `absolute`, it makes the elements to be removed from the normal flow of the document, so the parent element, in this case the wrapper, won't add the `height` of the absolute positioned children to its own.
Also, note that defining the parent's `position` to `relative` will affect the position of the children, as their position will be calculated in relation to the parent's position. If you don't want this behaviour just remove the `position: relative` from the `.wrapper` rule.

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/qEyn3/4/)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm... though width could be more

Comment: @popstack yes, I only tested it on Chrome. In Firefox and IE the `width` was too small. Anyway you can change it as you wish. :)

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in a div and set a border.

Try changing your html to this:

```
<div>
    <span id="h2">All right, Mate?</span>
    <span id="h3">All right, Mate?</span>
</div>​
```

And your css to this:

```
div {
    padding : 5px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 440px;
}
div span {
    width: 420px;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing:4pt;
    font-size:40pt;
    color:blue;
    position: relative;
}
div span#h2
{
    top:0px;
}
div span#h3
{
    top:-50px;
    left:20px;
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PJT9V/

Comment: I think you meant to link to this version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PJT9V/2/

Comment: @SurrealDreams no, no i did not... because that is the same thing as the base fiddle...

Comment: @Neal, I can't change my original code (h2, h3, etc.)...
... just tell me a minor addition/modification necessary

Answer (score 3):

You can put them both in a wrapper or you could try a `text-shadow` solution - something like this http://dabblet.com/gist/2769678